# Why smooth scrolling is not working on NextJs

Tags: reactjs, scroll, next.js

I found a script that would make smooth scrolling work on `next.js`.

Here's the repo:
https://gist.github.com/vinaypuppal/b7271ad84a0d69c9cfafaaa83afed199

I added all those required, and also add that change that the first comment suggested. But still as same as using `react/link`.

The problem is that it's not even calling this code:

```
  //#LinkSmoothScroll.js
  //...

  linkClicked(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    Router
      .push(this.props.href)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('test') //this one is not being called at all when I click the <LinkSmoothScroll>
        return smoothScroll(this.props.href)
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.props.done && this.props.done()
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.props.onError && this.props.onError(err)
        console.error(err)
      })
  }

  //...
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution, since when you are in the same page, you don't need to wait for `Router.push()` to get executed and then to continue with `smoothScrool()`, because it never will.

```
linkClicked(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const scrollX = window.pageXOffset;
    const scrollY = window.pageYOffset;

    const location = window.location;
    const href = this.props.href;

    if (location.pathname === href.split('#')[0]) {
      Router.push(this.props.href);
      window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
      return smoothScroll(this.props.href)
    }
    else {
      Router
        .push(this.props.href)
        .then(() => {
          window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
          return smoothScroll(this.props.href)
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.props.done && this.props.done()
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.props.onError && this.props.onError(err)
          console.error(err)
        })
    }
  }
```

So if you are in the same location, it will just move to that id, otherwise it will load page and then move it.